# Javascript one page dynamic div for mini pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have a one page website.
I have an area of the screen that is a div.
I want to be able to show different "mini" pages within this div based
on if the user clicks a button.
The contents of the div are html,javascript and images.

What is the best way to solve this?
I want it to be very responsive and fast, without re-loading the page itself.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

angular framework is great for single page apps. You can use the default ngRoute or the angular-ui-router to achieve the content swapping you want.